# Saving file contents to database and retrieving causing blank space at start of file

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a PHP project where I take a file upload from an HTML form and submit the contents of the file to the database. At a later point, the user can download the file, where it retrieves the file contents and echo the content to the browser.

This is mostly working except for one thing. When the file is re-download, it creates a blank few spaces at the start of the file. If I then remove the blank spaces it works fine. For example, I try to open a wav file, I get an error from Media Player stating that the file is corrupt or not supported. I remove the first line blank spaces from the file in notepad, re-open in media player and all is well.

When I look at the file contents within the database, everything looks to be OK, no blank spaces, so I believe it is in the download where this is happening.

Below is how I am writing the file contents to the database

```
private function writeFileToDatabase($fileName, $tmpName, $type, $fileSize, $fileArea, &$error, $isForCustomerPortal)
    {
        $fileName = mysqli_escape_string($this->conn, $fileName);
        $fileSize = mysqli_escape_string($this->conn, $fileSize);
        $type = mysqli_escape_string($this->conn, $type);
        $fileArea = mysqli_escape_string($this->conn, $fileArea);

        $tableName = null;
        if ($isForCustomerPortal)
        {
            $tableName = "portal_file_store";
        }
        else
        {
            $tableName = "file_store";
        }

        //Open the uploaded file
        $fh = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
        if (!$fh)
        {
            $error = "Could not open uploaded file";
            return false;
        }
        $content = fread($fh, filesize($tmpName));
        $content = mysqli_escape_string($this->conn, $content);
        fclose($fh);

        //Store the file in the database
        $query = "INSERT INTO $tableName (RecordID, Area, FileName, ContentType, Size, FileContent) "
            . "VALUES ('$this->recordID', '$fileArea', '$fileName', '$type', '$fileSize', '$content')";
        $result = $this->conn->query($query);

        if ($result)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            $error = mysqli_error($this->conn);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Below is how I am trying to retrieve and download the file from the database

```
function downloadFile($fileID, $isFromPortal = false)
    {
        $fileID = mysqli_escape_string($this->conn, $fileID);
        $tableName = "file_store";
        if ($isFromPortal)
        {
            $tableName = "portal_file_store";
        }

        $query = "SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE id='$fileID'";
        $result = $this->conn->query($query);
        if ($result)
        {
            $data = $result->fetch_array();
            header("Content-length: ".$data["Size"]);
            header("Content-type: ".$data["ContentType"]);
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$data["FileName"]);
            print $data["FileContent"];
            ob_clean();
            flush();
        }
        else
        {
            echo mysqli_error($this->conn);
        }
    }
```

### Update

The download function is called by JavaScript calling `window.location=download-file.php' this creates an object of a class which calls the downloadFile function as below

```
<?php
require_once 'DBHelper.php';
require_once 'ConfigManager.php';
require_once 'Defines.php';
require_once 'classes/FileManager/FileManager.php';
require_once 'classes/HelperClass.php';

if (!isset($_GET["file_id"]))
{
    exit();
}
session_start();

/*if (!HelperClass::isAPIAuthenticated($redirectURL))
{
    $responseArray =  HelperClass::generateResponseArray(API_NOT_AUTHENTICATED, "NotAuthenticated", false);
    $responseArray["redirectURL"] = $redirectURL;
    print json_encode($responseArray);
    exit();
}*/

if (!isset($_SESSION["AuthToken"]))
{
    $responseArray = HelperClass::generateResponseArray(API_NOT_AUTHENTICATED, "NotAuthenticated", false);
    $responseArray["redirectURL"] = $redirectURL;
    print json_encode($responseArray);
    exit();
}


$fileManager = new FileManager(null, null);

print $fileManager->downloadFile($_GET["file_id"], true);
```

Comment: Did you use `ob_start()` because you are using `ob_clean();`? If, check that all inlcudes files `classes, index.php` do not producing any whitspaces. Try to remove all closing Tags `?>` from the end of each php file.

Comment: Where do the spaces first appear - in the data you save to the database, or do they only show up when downloaded?

Comment: It looks like the white spaces get added in the download, when I look at the data in the database from MySQL workbench there is no whitespace at the start. I've also confirmed this by saving the blob content from MySQL workbench directly and opening the file and it works, so I'm pretty sure its in the download somewhere

Comment: There is likely whitespace in your PHP file. This happens a lot - make sure in the file that calls the downloadFile function that there are no spaces, line breaks or other whitespace characters at the top of the file.

Comment: @EatPeanutButter I've added some more info about how the function gets called. Its gets called by javascript to a PHP file, which creates an object of a class to call the download function, I've removed tabbing from the PHP open tag and removed the end PHP tag but no joy

Comment: Are there any whitespace characters before the php tags, OR any whitespace characters in any of those required files?

Comment: It depends on what is considered as whitespace, the tabbing has been removed and there is no blank line at the end of the file and no php end tag

Comment: have you tried to change print for a echo? Also this tutorial gives you a better way using filedescriptors http://www.web-development-blog.com/archives/php-download-file-script/

Comment: I have yea, it was an echo originally but tried print, now reverted back to echo but same thing

Comment: I'm not sure how, but its working, all I've done as mentioned is removed the tabbing after the open tag and removed the end php tag in the include files and the php file doing the download. This didn't seem to work but since restarted the browser and now it is so I guess maybe something cached